# Error: Characters found after SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access, sql

I am currently trying to insert a new row of information into a table, and am using the sql view inside of MS Access. When I run this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM VersionReleases;

INSERT INTO
  VersionReleases(CurrentVersionID, PreviousVersionID, ScriptID, ReleaseDate)
VALUES
  (555, 556, 1543, 2018);
```

It gives me an error specified in title, and I can't understand why.
Would appreciate some guidance, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop the SELECT statement. It is of no use here.

```
INSERT INTO VersionReleases
    (CurrentVersionID, PreviousVersionID, ScriptID, ReleaseDate)
VALUES
    (555, 556, 1543, 2018);
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access only supports the evaluation of **one SQL statement**; hence anything following a semi-colon delineating the end of a SQL statement will result in MS Access reporting the error:

> Characters found after end of SQL statement

[image]

As such, your query will need to become either:

```sql
SELECT * FROM VersionReleases;
```

Or:

```sql
INSERT INTO
    VersionReleases(CurrentVersionID, PreviousVersionID, ScriptID, ReleaseDate)
VALUES
    (555, 556, 1543, 2018);
```

With a new query created to contain the other SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use "go":

```
INSERT INTO employees (id, fi)
VALUES (1970, 'dfewf');
go
INSERT INTO employees (id, fi)
VALUES (1485, 'edwewrew');
go
INSERT INTO employees (id, fi)
VALUES (1719, 'fwefwefw');
```